# XUI Ajax example

Tags: xui

I don't understand how to use the XUI xhr (ajax) call.  Consider the following code:

```
x$('#left-panel').xhr('/panel', {
    async: true,
    callback: function() {
        alert("The response is " + this.responseText);
    },
   headers:{
       'Mobile':'true'
   }
});
```

So does this mean that when a user HOVERs over the left-panel, xui will make an ajax call to the url `/panel`, and give an alert statement on success?  But what if I wnat the ajax call to be execute ONBLUR instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [xui.js api docs](http://xuijs.com/docs/xhr) state that the xhr request...

> ... is always invoked on an element collection and uses the behaviour of html.

So, in your GET request to `/panel`, the response text would appear in an alert window because that's what your callback says to do. However, without the callback, it would load the response into the `#left-panel` element, as if you had used:

```
x$('#left-panel').xhr('/panel', {
   async: true,
   callback: function() {
       x$('#left-panel').html(this.responseText);
   },
   headers:{
       'Mobile':'true'
   }
});
```

That is to say, the above code should produce the same effect as:

```
x$('#left-panel').xhr('/panel', {
   async: true,
   headers:{
       'Mobile':'true'
   }
});
```

In addition, invocation of the xhr request is independent of the target element event. That is, it is not necessarily triggered by a hover (or blur). Let's say you wanted to bind to a click of the `#left-panel` element. You would then need something like:

```
x$('#left-panel').on('click', function(e){
    this.xhr('/panel', {
       async: true,
       callback: function() {
           alert("The response is " + this.responseText);
       },
       headers:{
           'Mobile':'true'
       }
    });
});
```